# What does HTTP 403 with substatus 72 mean on Azure and how to fix it?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, client-certificates

I have an App Service that's protected by a TLS certificate. It worked fine with small payloads, however, it started failing with larger payloads.
According to an article, I enabled certificate negotiation for my API Management Service:
https://notetoself.tech/2019/06/13/api-call-with-client-certificate-policy-failing-to-execute-due-to-message-size-on-azure-api-management/

However, it still randomly fails with certificate negotiation error, as seen below:

[image: Azure certificate negotiation error]

Important - I do not want to use client authentication between browser <-> API management. I'm using it only between API management <-> App Service.

I could not find any information on this substatus 72 code. What does it mean and can it be fixed? Is Azure client certificate authentication broken and won't work with large payloads?

Comment: side question: why are you using cert-based auth between APIM and AppServices? Are network layer-based restrictions not enough for you?

Comment: @silent To be honest, I'm not sure - that was what my customer wanted. Also, Microsoft documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates suggests that it's a common practice. But you are right, network layer-based restrictions might be enough for my case.

Comment: Yeah if you don't have a real, technical requirement I would not use certs, it's just overhead to manage (rotation...) plus puts overhead on your connection. Use IP restriction on your App service to allow only traffic from your APIM. If you are using APIM Premium, you could even use VNet injection to not at all rely on public IPs (but even that should be secure enough)

Answer (score 1):

The Negotiate Client Certificate checkbox will not help here as this is for the mutual auth between the client and your apim service where your problem is between apim and app service. Your app service should force apim to exchange the client certificate during the initial SSL handshake rather than waiting until it is needed.

This problem is not related specifically to azure, see this
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/networking-blog/https-client-certificate-request-freezes-when-the-server-is/ba-p/339672

The issue description to me or at least to how I understood it does not match with the error code as the 17 substatus code means that the client certificate has expired or is not yet valid.

See this https://www.google.com/search?q=403.17+http+code&oq=403.17+http+code&aqs=chrome..69i57.9265j0j7&client=ms-android-samsung-gn-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

And this https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/client-certificate-revisited-how-to-troubleshoot-client/ba-p/348053

Answer (score 1):

Posting a large file can fail if you enable Client Certificates
Article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/posting-a-large-file-can-fail-if-you-enable-client-certificates

You will see 403 72 in IIS logs.